# How to add delay to budiyev code scanner scanning event

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I am using budiyev:code-scanner library in my android project to scan QR codes. It is in continues scan mode. Is there a way to set a small delay time in one scan to another. Now it scan multiple records in a blink of an eye

```
mCodeScanner = new CodeScanner(getActivity(), binding.scannerView);
        mCodeScanner.setCamera(CodeScanner.CAMERA_BACK);
        mCodeScanner.setFormats(CodeScanner.ALL_FORMATS);
        mCodeScanner.setAutoFocusMode(AutoFocusMode.SAFE);
        mCodeScanner.setScanMode(ScanMode.CONTINUOUS);

@Override
            public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        binding.scanCode.setText(result.getText());
                        scannedQr = result.getText();
                        getDetails(scannedQr);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it.
When Scan event triggered you have to release the scanner reaource so it stop canning again. After the work is done again call `mCodeScanner.startPreview();`

```
@Override
            public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        binding.scanCode.setText(result.getText());
                        scannedQr = result.getText();
                        mCodeScanner.releaseResources();
                        getDetails(mCodeScanner);
                    }
                });
            }
```